# Syntax Errors while building jtgrassie/pyrx on Windows [jit_compiler_x86_static.S, program_prologue_linux.inc,program_read_dataset_sshash_init.inc]

Tags: mining, windows, python

The Commands:

```
>>> git clone https://github.com/jtgrassie/pyrx.git
>>> git submodule update --init --recursive -q
>>> py setup.py build
```

Result: pybind11[complete]
        RandomX[Several syntax errors]
        Example: fatal error C1021: Illegal command "Copyright".

So far i was able to accomplish comments by using the c++ Comment Syntax

i need some resyources for adjusting the syntax

Addationally program_read_dataset_sshash_fin.inc is inpossible to be implimented by the compiler, i would also need resources for this assembly and its reimplementation.

Errors:

```
in  >>> pip install git+https://github.com/jtgrassie/pyrx
out >>> 
---------------------------------
Building wheel for pyrx (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\azes\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AzeS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AzeS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-g4jrtr0a'
       cwd: C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\
  Complete output (191 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.17763.
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28314.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28314.0
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/AzeS/Anaconda3/python.exe (found version "3.7.3")
  -- Found PythonLibs: C:/Users/AzeS/Anaconda3/libs/Python37.lib
  -- pybind11 v2.4.dev4
  -- Setting default build type: Release
  -- Performing Test _maes_cxx
  -- Performing Test _maes_cxx - Failed
  -- Performing Test _maes_c
  -- Performing Test _maes_c - Failed
  -- Performing Test HAVE_SSSE3
  -- Performing Test HAVE_SSSE3 - Failed
  -- Performing Test HAVE_AVX2
  -- Performing Test HAVE_AVX2 - Failed
  -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS
  -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS - Success
  -- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG
  -- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG - Success
  -- LTO enabled
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/AzeS/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release
  Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 16.4.0+e901037fe f\x81r .NET Framework
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
-----------------------------
C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\external\RandomX\src\jit_compiler_x86_static.S(1,1): fatal error C1021: Ung\x81ltiger Pr▒prozessorbefehl "Copyright". [C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\external\RandomX\randomx.vcxproj]
    Code wird generiert...
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\setup.py", line 68, in <module>
      zip_safe=False,
    File "C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\setup.py", line 32, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\setup.py", line 57, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '--build', '.'] + build_args, cwd=self.build_temp)
    File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyrx
  Running setup.py clean for pyrx
Failed to build pyrx
Installing collected packages: pyrx
    Running setup.py install for pyrx: started
    WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1252
    WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1252
    Running setup.py install for pyrx: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\azes\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AzeS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AzeS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-eamuz154\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\azes\anaconda3\Include\pyrx'
         cwd: C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\
------------------------------------------------------
 C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\external\RandomX\src\jit_compiler_x86_static.S(1,1): fatal error C1021: Ung\x81ltiger Pr▒prozessorbefehl "Copyright". [C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\external\RandomX\randomx.vcxproj]
      Code wird generiert...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\setup.py", line 68, in <module>
        zip_safe=False,
      File "C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\setup.py", line 32, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\setup.py", line 57, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '--build', '.'] + build_args, cwd=self.build_temp)
      File "c:\users\azes\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\azes\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AzeS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AzeS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-kd7m4uoa\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-eamuz154\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\azes\anaconda3\Include\pyrx' Check the logs for full command output.
--------------------------------------------------
in  >>> git clone && cd && py setup.py build
out >>> 
ERR: Syntax errors as mentioned
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 68, in <module>
    zip_safe=False,
  File "C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\AzeS\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\AzeS\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\AzeS\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\AzeS\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\AzeS\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\AzeS\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 32, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "setup.py", line 57, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '--build', '.'] + build_args, cwd=self.build_temp)
  File "C:\Users\AzeS\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This StackExchange is not a general python/code support channel. That said...
2. You did not follow the installation instructions in the repository readme. Quoting:

> pip install git+https://github.com/jtgrassie/pyrx

3. I have only tested on *nix platforms though I have had reports from others who have used on Windows also.
4. Your errors are stemming from your compiler not knowing how to treat one or more of the assembly source files in the RandomX library.

Comment: Ive read the readme, i always read the readme. 
i even tried it in git bash: 
Errors:  
  raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\azes\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AzeS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-yykpgym1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AzeS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-yykpgym1\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-yvo6f61f'

Comment: cwd: C:\Users\AzeS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-yykpgym1\
  Complete output (191 lines):

Comment: And compilation errors

Comment: ive added some errors, i would appriciate it if we could hold a skype conversation or if you could ask the people who installed it on win

Comment: Does the readme say use 'git bash'? No. By the looks of your output it is failing to build the randomx library.

Comment: I'm sure if you ask nicely on IRC you will find the person/people who have used it on Windows. As I have said, I have only built and tested this on *nix platforms.

Comment: IRC sounds good, which IRC ? ^^ Any chance to skype with you? i will also do a push request afterwards